# Indexing with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Entity Framework seems to always perform, essentially, a `"SELECT *"` when I access a entity. This makes sense, since the ORM is allowing me to treat the response as an object - all properties should be accessible in the response.

In a read-heavy scenario, does this mean that I should tend to prefer a full coverage index when building non-clustered indexes? Otherwise, it seems like I'd **always** end up with the additional lookup on the clustered index.

I'm not suggesting full coverage for all NC indexes - just for the ones that are trying to be fully optimized.

Comment: If you include all your columns in an index, that index will become as large and inefficient as your table, if I understand you correctly. Just make sure you do PK lookups.

Comment: You're right about the "as large as" but perhaps a bit off on the inefficiency. When you build the index, you specify what should be the key of the index in addition to what should be included in the leaves of the index (optionally). What I'm referring to is including all properties in the index, and hence the index would be large in size. However, in regards to efficiency, an optimized lookup is possible, whereas the table scan of a heap would be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In all discussions that I had about this subject, the conclusion was the EF, and others frameworks are excellent to work with an only or a small set of data because they are optimized to work with keys.

The another problem is when you use early-load your object can be load if unnecessary data but is easy to access all properties, on the other hand, when you use late-load you need additional code to retrieve the data and assure that all necessary properties will be load at the use moment. These strategies can impact to the matter that you will plan your indexes.

When is need to work with a lot of information, for example, to fill a grid, execute a SQL Command is more efficient because you will load only necessary data.